# Exception : Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

Though this question has asked, the answer could not solve my problem.
I used `commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar`and`postgres jdbc driver`. I checked `postgresql-8.4-702.jdbc4.jar, postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar, postgresql-9.2-1004.jdbc4.jar, postgresql-9.3-1103.jdbc4.jar, postgresql-9.3-1103.jdbc41.jar, postgresql-9.4-1202.jdbc4.jar` and `postgresql-9.4-1202.jdbc41.jar` one after another. But none of the implement the isValid function and always throw exception.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented.)] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:753)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.isValid(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:102)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(Jdbc4Connection.java:21)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:918)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2307)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2290)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2039)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.openConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:82)
    at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.getConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:68)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.getConnection(BaseExecutor.java:315)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:61)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:303)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:102)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:82)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:120)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:386)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:205)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:122)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:64)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:53)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.getAllParty(Unknown Source)
    at com.votersvoicemyanmar.resource.ArticleController.getAllArticles(ArticleController.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any solution?

Comment: At a guess you have more than one copy of the JDBC driver on the classpath. What does `org.postgresql.Driver.getVersion()` say?

Comment: It prints PostgreSQL 8.4 JDBC4 (build 702), I think I removed the lib which i do not use from build path to make sure that more than one copy is not there..

Comment: Now I got it, though I removed the driver from build path. I did not delete the drivers I did not use from my lib folder. That's the reason. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one copy of the JDBC driver on the CLASSPATH.

Check the output of `org.postgresql.Driver.getVersion ()`